# Question formation

Tags: questions, formal-language

The Barnes are planning a trip **to Norway.**
Ask about the text in bold..

The answer in the website was:
Where are the Barnes planning a trip?

It sounds to me that he is asking for where they are at the moment. Not to where they are planning to head to.

And my answer was: To where are the barnes planning a trip?
I don't know if you cant put "to" before "where" but it sounds better than putting it at the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Your question (as an answer)

> To where are the Barnes planning a trip?

Is correct and understandable, and gives emphasis on the destination.

It seems to me the reason for the website answer

> Q: Where are the Barnes planning a trip?
>   A: *to Norway*

is **literally** because the highlighted part is **to Norway**. However, a more natural sounding question would be

> Where are the Barnes planning a trip to?

Also, why do you think ending in **to** is inappropriate?

There is a school of thought that dictates to never end a sentence with a preposition, but you have also ended a sentence in your question with **to** and there are no problems with it.